# select drop down choose country depending on the location of state in the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have countries which is an array of hashes as follows

```
countries = [
      {
        "country" => {
          "name" => "USA"
          "id" => "123"
        },
        "states" => [
          {
            "name" => "Alaska",
            "id"=> "b2"
          },
          {
            "name"=> "Kansas",
            "id"=> "b6"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "country" => {
          "name" => "India"
          "id" => "123"
        },       
        "states" => [
          {
            "name"=> "Karnataka",
            "id"=> "b31",
          },
          {
            "name" =>"Punjab",
            "id"=> "b21"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

In my ruby code I get an array for all states  and countries listed above:

```
def country
   countries.map { |country|
   [country.name, country.id]
 }
end

def state
  countries.flat_map { |country|
  country.states.map { |state|
    [state.name, state.id]
  }
}
end

My form select_tag is as follows:

= select_tag 'state', options_for_select(state)
= select_tag 'country', options_for_select(country)
```

The above select drop down pulls all states and countries.

Now, I need to tweak select drop down so that if any of the states belongs to the first entry of the array , then chose the country from the same entry and so on.

In the above example if Kansas is chosen select USA as the country.

If Punjab is selected chose India as the country.

I dont know if its possible. It seems way too hacky to me.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is create a hash with state id as key and country id as value

like this

```
COUNTRY.inject({}) do |hash, ele| 
     ele['states'].each {|state| hash[state['id']] = ele['country']['id']} 
  hash
end
```

you will get hash like this

```
{"b2"=>"123", "b6"=>"123", "b31"=>"123", "b21"=>"123"}
```

load this hash as json in your view and write jquery event on state select change.
On state find country id from json object and select that id as country for that state.